# How to retrieve and add the value from one collection to another.. Mongoose , Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, simultaneous

Asset and Assetlist are two different collection. If a assetlist got created i want to add the quantity of the assetlist to asset quantity. Could anyone please suggest how to achieve this..

```js
app.post("/assetlists/new", function(req, res){
   var astname = req.body.astname;
   var brand = req.body.brand;
   var quantity1 = req.body.quantity;
   var purchasedate = req.body.purchasedate;
   var newAssetlist = {astname: astname, brand: brand, quantity: quantity, purchasedate: purchasedate};
   Assetlist.create(newAssetlist, function(err, newlyCreated){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else{
           res.redirect("/assetlists");
           console.log("Working create");
       }
   });
   
   Asset.findOneAndUpdate({ name: astname }, {$set:{ quantity: quantity1}}, function(err, updatedAssetquantity){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
        
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

Here we are using **$inc** in the update query. The Update query is called in the callback after the creation of a AssetList.

```js
app.post("/assetlists/new", function (req, res) {
    var astname = req.body.astname;
    var brand = req.body.brand;
    var quantity1 = req.body.quantity;
    var purchasedate = req.body.purchasedate;
    var newAssetlist = {astname: astname, brand: brand, quantity: quantity, purchasedate: purchasedate};
    Assetlist.create(newAssetlist, function (err, newlyCreated) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Working created", newlyCreated);
            Asset.findOneAndUpdate({name: astname}, {$inc: {quantity: 1}}, function (err, updatedAssetquantity) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("updatedAssetquantity", updatedAssetquantity);
                    res.redirect("/assetlists");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you.